# Accept documents using MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have most of the workings down and functional, there is one thing however that I am struggling to get my head around. What essentially happens is a person opens the form on an Excel sheet, fills it out and submits to the sheet.

At the bottom of the form there is an option to upload 2 documents, each is using its own button to display the file explorer. One of the forms MQF094 is always required, the second MQF095 is only required sometimes. Whenever they add a document to the form, the name of that document is displayed in a text box so the user can check that they have attached the right document before submitting to the sheet.

What I am trying to do is when a person clicks 'Submit' on the form a message box appears asking them if MQF095 is required, if they click no then the info is posted to the sheet as normal, if they click yes then they are prompted to add a form using the file explorer.

Currently if a person only adds MQF094 it works fine, however if they add both an MQF094 and MQF095 form, they are both posted to the sheet but in name only, there is no link to the actual document. This link however works just if only posting MQF094

The code for this is below. I can post my full code is necessary:

```
Dim TargetRow As Integer
Dim answer As Integer

TargetRow = Sheets("Backend").Range("K3").Value + 1

If MQF095Text.Value = "" Then
answer = MsgBox("Does an MQF095 form need to be added?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "MQF095 Query")
End If

        If answer = vbYes Then
        Sheets("Software Evaluation").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Software Evaluation").Range("Software_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 6), Address:=stpPath _
        , TextToDisplay:=MQF095Text.Value
        
        Else: answer = vbNo

        Sheets("Software Evaluation").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Software Evaluation").Range("Software_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 5), Address:=strPath _
        , TextToDisplay:=MQF094Text.Value
        
        With Sheets("Software Evaluation").Range("Software_Start")
        .Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = SoftwareNam
        .Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value = SupplierName
        .Offset(TargetRow, 3).Value = PrincipalApp
        .Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value = TypeCombo
        .Offset(TargetRow, 5).Value = MQF094Text
         .Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value = MQF095Text
            End With
                  End If
                  
       
              
MsgBox "Software Entry Added Successfully", vbOKOnly, "Software Added"
```

Comment: The line of code after `Exit Sub` will not execute. I guess the `Exit Sub` should be the last line in the `If answer = vbYes Then` block.

Comment: If I put the Exit Sub after the line for assigning a document link I get an error. I essentially wanted the if loop to reset if a person click 'Yes. I thought putting Exit Sub where it is would essentially break out of that if statement but would be fine if a person clicked no

Comment: _I get an error_ - What is the error ?

Comment: invalid procedure call

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Is **stp**Path the path to MQF095 and **str**Path the path to MQF094, 2 variables ?

Comment: Yes that's right, 2 different location stores for 2 different documents

Comment: I have made some amendments to the code to make it simpler, the line that throws an error is the one directly after     If answer = vbYes Then. 

If I click No in the msgbox everything is fine, if I click yes then the error is thrown

Comment: The logic seems odd - you have `If MQF095Text.Value = ""` ask question and if answer is yes adding a link with `TextToDisplay:=MQF095Text.Value` . This might be the invalid procedure error. Should that be `If MQF095Text.Value <> ""`

Comment: No because if MQF095Text.Value <> "" that means that someone has already added a document and so the Yes/No msgbox will not need to be displayed anyway. The reason I have it like MQF095Text.Value == "" is because an MQF095 isn't always needed, the msgbox displays whenever one hasn't been added, just in case one does need to be. Hence why if the person clicks 'No' the form should just submit whatever it has, if they click 'Yes' then a file explorer window should open so they can add one.

Comment: So what text is to be displayed with `TextToDisplay:=MQF095Text.Value` if `MQF095Text.Value = ""`.  ?

Comment: If the code worked then the sheet wouldn't display anything, if the code did work then it would display the name of the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251415/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-strexxin).

Answer (score 0):

Try if this is the correct logic

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim TargetRow As Integer, answer As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    
    ' test values
    Const strPath = "C:\" ' MQF094 file
    Const stpPath = "C:\" ' MQF095 file
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Software Evaluation")
    Set rng = ws.Range("Software_Start")
    TargetRow = Sheets("Backend").Range("K3").Value + 1

    If MQF095Text.Value = "" Then
         answer = MsgBox("Does an MQF095 form need to be added?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "MQF095 Query")
    End If

    With rng
        .Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = SoftwareNam
        .Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value = SupplierName
        .Offset(TargetRow, 3).Value = PrincipalApp
        .Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value = TypeCombo
        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Offset(TargetRow, 5), _
             Address:=strPath, TextToDisplay:=MQF094Text.Value
             
        If answer = vbYes Then
             ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Offset(TargetRow, 6), _
             Address:=stpPath, TextToDisplay:=""
        Else
            .Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value = MQF095Text.Value
        End If
        
    End With
                                     
    MsgBox "Software Entry Added Successfully", vbOKOnly, "Software Added"
    
End Sub
```